# Convert a while loop into a for loop in Python 3.3

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.x, while-loop

I am trying to convert this while loop into a for loop, but I do not know how to go about in doing it.

```
output = ''
i = 0
while i <len(MyArray):
    C = chr(int(MyArray[i],2))
    output = output + C
    i = i + 1

print(output)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
output = ''
for i in range(len(MyArray)):
    C = chr(int(MyArray[i],2))
    output = output + C

print(output)
```

or

```
output = ''
for element in MyArray:
    C = chr(int(element,2))
    output = output + C

print(output)
```

or

```
output = [chr(int(element,2)) for element in MyArray]
print ''.join(output)
```

Comment: Hi, its coming up with the error that output is not defined when I have tried either of your solutions

Comment: yeah it got lost when copying your code but it should have been quite obvious how to fix that :)

Comment: though, please avoid solution 1, prefer to that solution 2 or solution 3!